# How to execute bash script on RPi via android ssh?

Tags: bash, command

I have created a bash script and made it executable. The script works and does what it should. It does require the user password when I execute it via SSH on the computer.

Where it fails is when I try to send the same command via android with a small app that can send commands via ssh. it logs in via ssh with the user/pass no problem (the app doesnt give any feedback as to why it does not launch the script, but I have a feeling its because of the authentication after trying to execute the command it requires the user's password).
I have downloaded raspicheck to my android which can send commands remotely via SSH. It does not seem to work thought.

The command I am trying to send from the android is simply "sh startvpn.sh"

Would appeciate any help, thanks

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: the only command i tried remotely was sh startvpn.sh and that only works if I am on a computer via putty. It then asks for the password and then runs the script. If I try that same command via the android app, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question so much as it is a Linux-in-general question. That said, have you tried using `sudo sh startvpn.sh`?

Comment: I apologise if I am writing in the wrong section or forum, as I am a quite new to the hole linux experience. Even with sudo in front of the command it still requests the user password to launch the script.

Comment: If I wait long enough with the android app it comes back to me saying: Authenticating pasword--- Connection established (Then after I guess its trying to launch the command) then it says error - a transport exception occured. Check your connection, reason: timeout expired

Comment: ok now when i run sh statvpn.sh it says sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified.

Comment: i solved my problem with echo 'your_pass' | sudo -S command thanks